# Signing with Ledger outside of the browser

Tags: ledger

I want to write a script to rotate a validator's session key on a Ledger without using the browser.

I have been using polkadot.js UI for this purpose, but is it possible to write a typescript program to do it? This would need to access the USB bus in order to communicate with the Ledger. It would then send the transaction out using polkadot.js API.

Answer (score 3):

You can totally do that, you could check out [the asset-cli-tool](https://github.com/paritytech/asset_cli_tool), especially the [ledger signer](https://github.com/paritytech/asset_cli_tool/blob/303fd4b58448d49a60197c93ab14dbf83eb87823/blockchainServices/setup.ts#L64) for some guidance and an example on how to use the Ledger to sign some tx and PJS to submit it, but it's not something too complicated.